# How to get a compressed zip file size in c# (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there anyway of doing this in c#?

I can get the amount of bytes that a zip contains via a filestream but there seems nothing for finding the compressed file size.

Comment: Are you asking to get how much size the compressed file would be _after_ being unzipped?

Comment: By _compressed file size_ do you mean the size of the original files or the zipped output?

Comment: basically I am getting unzipped file(s), going to compressed then and hen find out what the compressed size on disk is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("yourfile.zip");
long filesize = f.Length; // file size in bytes
```

Comment: Thought it was .length, just wanted to check and not to be stupid. Thanks